# Should this situation use the vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to build a blog with a simple 3-part structure: `<header>`, `<nav>`, and `<main>` using Vue.

The `<main>` section is dynamic, and the rest is static. I'm not sure if I should just hard-code the fixed `<header>` and `<nav>` sections or write them using Vue components as well.

What criteria can I use to make the decision?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you need it once, just write it. If you need it twice, *then* consider a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criteria'll be the performance. If you import to components which can be done without really using components will reduce your app's performance.
I think hard code those parts will be good.